# How to define column sized in a large table (368 columns )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[TABLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl6fI.png)

I need to expand the width/height of task title column, and adjust the width/height of certain cells.

I tried following it works if number of columns under 10

```
<td style="height:10px;width:100px">Java</td>
```

Comment: Do you want to expand hight and width for certain cells right, not for all?

Comment: Have you tried with css like `.class{width:auto; height:auto;}` ?

Comment: @Firoz Tennali  Yes,Only for certain cells

Comment: Try to use something like this <td width="pixels|%">

Answer (score 0):

First give width: max-content in table tag and after that give width in td tag as you want then it will work , For example

```
<table style="width: max-content;">
<td style="height:10px;width:100px">Java</td>
</table>
```